# Auto mount partition

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, automount

Apart from /, /home and swap partitions, I've created one more partition, just for storage. How can I make that partition auto mount somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically add a partition at boot, you need to add its data to `/etc/fstab`. See `man fstab` for more info, or ask here if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PySDM](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/) to configure what partitions need to be mounted. PySDM is a Py-GTK front end of sorts to `/etc/fstab`

To install it in Ubuntu, type `apt-get install pysdm` at the terminal or just search for PySDM in the software centre.

[image]